# codeigniter alert if image size exceeds

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

Hi I have this code for uploading an  image. I can perfectly add the image but I want to add restrictions and there will an alert that will pop up if image size exceeds but I don't know how can add I alert if image size exceeds. please help me

Here's my code:

CONTROLLERS:

```
public function upload_file()
{
    $filename = 'r_image';
    $status = "";
    $msg = "";



    $config['upload_path'] = 'img/recipes/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8 ;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = true;

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($filename))
    {
        $stats = 'error';
        $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
    }else{
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        if($uploadData['file_name'])
        {
            $thumnail = 'img/recipes/'.$uploadData['file_name'];
        }else{
            $thumnail = 'No thumnbail uploaded!';
        }

        $updateThumbData = array('recipe_id' => $recipe_id,
                                 'r_image'   => $thumnail
            );

        $this->products_model->updataRecipeThumnail($updateThumbData);

        redirect('dashboard/view_product');

    }           /* upload_file() */


}
```

Answer (score 0):

for uploading files you must use **POST** method. read this [w3schools file upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

```
 if($_FILES['Your_POST_name']['size']>1024 * 8 )// to check what is your post name print_r($_FILES);
{
     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>Image is too big!</div>');
            redirect('dashboard/view_product');
}
```

and in your view_product's view file, add following code to display error

```
 <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
```

Important things to remember while dealing with file uploads in php.

> Make sure that the form uses method="post"
>
> The form also needs the following attribute:
>   enctype="multipart/form-data". It specifies which content-type to use
>   when submitting the form

Without the requirements above, the file upload will not work.

Comment: i am not using post.

Comment: So what you are using?